# Visual Studio Exception Thrown: write acces violation. q_deck->p_deck was 0x110112. C LANGUAGE

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, struct

Im getting that weird error, and don't know what to do. I tried to find the solution, but couldn't find the one, working for me. It's card game, and the error shows when i'm trying to add card to my list, which is a deck of cards. Here's my entire code, to fully understand my idea. It is written in c, but i'm using cin / cout from c++, thats why i have "using namespace std;" Thank you for help :)

```
#define SIZE 52
#define HALF_SIZE 26

using namespace std;

typedef enum Suit { Diamonds, Hearts, Spades, Clubs } Suit_t;
typedef enum Power { Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace } Power_t;

typedef struct card {
    Suit_t suit;
    Power_t power;
}cards;

typedef struct deck {
    cards* p_deck;
    int size;
}decks;

void Deck_Creator(cards* deck) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        deck[i].suit = (Suit)(i / 13);
        deck[i].power = (Power)(i % 13);
    }

}

void Display_Deck(cards* deck) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {

        if (deck[i].suit == 0) {
            cout << "Diamond ";
        }
        else if (deck[i].suit == 1) {
            cout << "Heart ";
        }
        else if (deck[i].suit == 2) {
            cout << "Spade ";
        }
        else {
            cout << "Club ";
        }
        cout << " " << deck[i].power << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Deck_Shuffler(cards* deck) {
    int changer = 0;               // Index of changed card
    cards temp = {};             // Temporary holding place for changing
    srand(time(NULL));            // Function to get random numbers with current time
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        changer = rand() % SIZE;   // Generating random number from 0 to 51
        temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[changer];  // if changer = i
        deck[changer] = temp;
    }
}

void Deck1_Creator(cards* deck, cards* deck1, decks* q_deck1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < HALF_SIZE; i++) {
        memcpy(&deck1[i], &deck[i], sizeof(cards));  // Copying content using memcpy function
    }
    q_deck1->p_deck = deck1;
    q_deck1->size = HALF_SIZE;
}

void Deck2_Creator(cards* deck, cards* deck2, decks* q_deck2) {
    int i = HALF_SIZE;
    for (int i = 26; i < SIZE; i++) {
        deck2[i - HALF_SIZE] = deck[i];   // Simple copying struct array content into another array
    }
    q_deck2->p_deck = deck2;
    q_deck2->size = HALF_SIZE;
}

void table_creator(decks* q_deck) {
    q_deck->p_deck = {};
    q_deck->size = 0;
}

void enqueue(decks* q_deck, cards card) {
    // I TRIED THAT TOO
    //int n;
    //n = q_deck->size;
    q_deck->p_deck[q_deck->size] = card;
    q_deck->size++;
}

cards* dequeue(decks* q_deck) {
    cards tmp_card;

    tmp_card = q_deck->p_deck[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < q_deck->size - 1; i++) {
        q_deck->p_deck[i] = q_deck->p_deck[i + 1];
    }
    q_deck->size--;

    return &tmp_card;
}

void disp_queue(decks* q_deck) {
    for (int i = 0; i < q_deck->size; i++) {
        cout << q_deck->p_deck[i].suit <<" ";
        cout << q_deck->p_deck[i].power << endl;
    }
}

int main() {                   
    cards deck[SIZE];
    cards deck1[SIZE];
    cards deck2[SIZE];
    cards table1[HALF_SIZE];
    cards table2[HALF_SIZE];
    decks q_deck1;
    decks q_deck2;
    decks q_table1;
    decks q_table2;
    char choice;

    table_creator(&q_table1);
    table_creator(&q_table2);

    for(; ;) {  //Never ending loop
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
        case '1':
            cout << endl << "Unshuffled deck: " << endl;
            Deck_Creator(deck);
            Display_Deck(deck);
            break;
        case '2':
            cout << endl << "Shuffled deck: " << endl;
            Deck_Shuffler(deck);
            Display_Deck(deck);
            break;
        case '3':
            cout << endl << "Hand 1:" << endl;
            Deck1_Creator(deck, deck1, &q_deck1);
            disp_queue(&q_deck1);
            break;
        case '4':
            cout << endl << "Hand 2:" << endl;
            Deck2_Creator(deck, deck2, &q_deck2);
            disp_queue(&q_deck2);
            break;
        case '5':
            cards tmp_card = *dequeue(&q_deck1);
            enqueue(&q_table1, tmp_card);
            tmp_card = *dequeue(&q_deck2);
            enqueue(&q_table2, tmp_card);
            disp_queue(&q_table1);
            disp_queue(&q_table2);
            break;
        case '6':
            disp_queue(&q_deck1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ERROR Pops only when im pressing case 5 in my switch function. The rest works well. 
ERROR Pops in this function:

```
cards* dequeue(decks* q_deck) {
    cards tmp_card;

    tmp_card = q_deck->p_deck[0];              // EXACTLY IN THIS LINE RED X OCCURS
    for (int i = 0; i < q_deck->size - 1; i++) {
        q_deck->p_deck[i] = q_deck->p_deck[i + 1];
    }
    q_deck->size--;

    return &tmp_card;
}
```

Please help me with understanding of this error, so that I will fully know why, and how this error works :(
Thank You for all your time, i know it's pretty long code.

Comment: If you're starting your program and immediately choosing 5, you're invoking undefined behavior as soon as you `tmp_card = q_deck->p_deck[0];` since you're not allocating any space for `p_deck`. I don't know what `q_deck->p_deck = {};` does.. perhaps set the pointer to a local empty array that goes out of scope when `table_creator` returns? Either way, that's not what you want. `p_deck` must point to valid memory that's dynamically allocated or to a `cards` structure that's in scope.

Comment: the operators `cin` and `cout` are ONLY found in the C++ language, The `namespace` is ONLY found in the C++ language.  So if your using those operators, then your writing C++, not C

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `if (deck[i].suit == 0) {`  This is using a 'magic' number.  This will be a problem when maintenance, editing, etc are performed.  Suggest: `if ( deck[i].suit == Diamonds ) {`

Comment: regarding: `typedef enum Power { Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace } Power_t;`  This will be a source of mis-understandings.  Suggest: `typedef enum Power { Two=2, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace } Power_t;`  Notice the initialization of the first entry to match the expected value.  BTW: it is typical for `enum` names and `typedef` names and `#define` names to be all caps so they are not mistaken for variables

Comment: @yano I tried to fix this, just like You said, but i think i still dont get it. You mean to malloc some value for p_deck? Could You tell me, where and how? Your help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: q_deck->p_deck = {}; Was meant to make an empty table, where cards from players will be thrown.

Comment: Okay. Finally i got this. No need to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yano is right about the lack of memory assigned to p_deck. I'm kind of surprised the others are working at all (you don't seem to be allocating any space at all for cards here, instead you're just writing the card values into areas next to your pointer, which don't technically belong to your pointer and aren't guaranteed to stay the same).

You can fix this by adding a constructor / destructor to your struct which handles assigning memory, since you're using C++.

```
typedef struct deck {
    cards* p_deck;
    int size;

    //constructor
    deck() : size(SIZE) //this sets the size to your size constant
    { 
        p_deck = malloc(size * sizeof(*p_deck)); //this gives p_deck memory space
    } 

    //destructor
    ~deck()
    {
        if(p_deck) delete[] p_deck; //this clears up the memory assigned to p_deck
        p_deck = nullptr;
    }

}deck; //edited so it matches the actual struct name
```

To use the constructor, when you create an object use `deck varName = deck();` instead of `deck varName;`.

The destructor is automatically called when the object goes out of scope (at the end of main() or its local function). You can also call it manually if you want to release the memory for whatever reason (e.g. if you want to re-create a whole new deck) with `varName.~deck();`

Comment: Oh, thanks for advice. Unfortunately im working on c, not c++. Cin and cout, are the only things that i can use from c++ in my project. Could you help me how to implement something like those "destructors" above, but in C? Would be great :)